# Как дать блоку полную высоту?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть такой блок: [codepen.io/Nikulio/pen/mAZKoO](http://codepen.io/Nikulio/pen/mAZKoO)

По идее, блок растягивается по высоте картинки, но эта высота не даётся `div.box_text`.
Можно дать ему фиксированную высоту, но это костыль.
Что посоветуете сделать?

**Вопрос:** Как дать `div.box_text` такую же высоту, как и у `div.box_img`?

Comment: использовать display: table или display: flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1 применить **flex**:

```
section.boxes {
    ... 
    div.box {
      ...
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
      align-content: stretch;
      justify-content: center;

      div.box_text {
            ....
            //height: 100%; убрать высоту
      }
    }
...
}
```

Вариант 2 **table**:

```
section.boxes {
    ... 
    div.box {
      ...
      display: table;
      height: 100%;

      div.box_text {
            ...
            display: table-cell;
            height: 100%; 
      }
    }
...
}
```

... еще можно применить варианты с `position: absolute;` (на крайний случай, как костыль).

Comment: Вариант с JS точно отпадает?)

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, если так хочется, то можете и js )

Comment: По поводу ваших советов - таблица точно нет, а вот флекс... ваше отношение к этой технологии?Как поддержка на телефонах?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: ещё вариант с 100vh - забыли